# Complexity of graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Last year, Laszlo Babai proved that the graph isomorphism problem can be solved in time:

$$ \exp(O(\log^c n)) $$

where $n$ is the number of vertices.

What is the best bound we have for $c$? (The case $c = 1$ would correspond to a polynomial-time algorithm for graph isomorphism.)

Comment: C=1 would actually be linear. (Unless you are hiding a constant inside exp()?)  Gerhard "Sometimes Dreams Of Linear Life" Paseman, 2016.03.28.

Comment: Yes, just allow me to move that big O inside the exp...

Comment: I may be misremembering, but I think I recall Babai saying something like his proof should give $c=7$, possibly after some optimizations. If not, in that general ballpark.

Comment: Yeah, in his talk at CMU I vaguely remember him saying something like $c = 11$.

Answer (score 4):

Babai apparently retracted some parts of his proof, now he claims that he can do $O(\exp(n^c))$ for some small $c$ (say, $c=0.01$), but not all $c>0$. See http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/update.html

Comment: It would be more clear to say that the claim of quasi polynomial time is retracted.  This may affect the proofs of the runtime analysis, but the core results are unchanged, if I read the announcement correctly.  Gerhard "Core Theory Is Important Too" Paseman, 2017.01.04.

Comment: Actually, he can do $O(\mathrm{exp}(n^c))$ for all $c$; his claim is $\mathrm{exp}(\mathrm{exp}(O(\sqrt{\log n})))$ (modulo some polylog factors in the $O()$).

Comment: Since then, Babai corrected the proof, the quasipolinomial claim holds again.

Comment: Now claims quasipolynomial again: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/update.html

Comment: It seems useful to point out [Aleksandar Makelov: *Graph Isomorphism in quasipolynomial time*. Part III Essay. Cambridge. 2015](https://amakelov.github.io/math/part-iii/essay/essay.pdf). This is the only independent exposition currently known to me. Makelov's nice essay is in particular very careful and explicit about its own *mode of organizing the material*. This mention does not express any opinion of mine about the correctness of either about Babai's proof or Makelov's work.